# Как найти среднее значение каждых X подряд идущих строк в SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Предположим, есть следующая таблица:

```
 product | price
------------------
  A      | 10
  B      | 20
  C      | 45
  D      | 47
  E      | 10
  F      | 60
  G      | 15
  H      | 15
  I      | 90
```

Нужно получить что-то вроде (для X = 3):

```
 products  |  avg
------------------
  A        |  25    -- 10+20+45
  D        |  39    -- 47+10+60
  G        |  40    -- 15+15+90
```

Как мне это сделать?

РЕД: Задана сортировка по возрастанию по колонке product.

Comment: В реляционных базах данных порядок строк не гарантирован. Поэтому в SQL нет понятия "подряд идущие строки" самого по себе. Подряд идущие строки могут быть только при заданной сортировке. У вас явно должна быть сортировка по колонке `products`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, да, простите, в условии задана сортировка по возрастанию по колонке product.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать аналитические функции с "плавающим окном". Например для oracle как это делается можно посмотреть тут http://www.interface.ru/fset.asp?Url=/oracle/anal-itiv.htm .

Comment: @faksel, я посмотрел, но все-таки не совсем понял, что из этого всего мне поможет решить проблему. Подозреваю, что все это дело с RANGE/ROWS BETWEEN и т.д. и есть то, что мне нужно, но по данной статье у меня никак не получается разобраться во всех этих PRECEDING и FOLLOWING. Есть еще ресурсы с подобной информацией?

Comment: @J.Doe, http://oracleplsql.ru/lead-function.html , например можно использовать проставив смещение на 1 , 2 и 3 позиции в подзапросе и посчитать результат во внешнем запросе. Оконные функции описаны тут http://my-oracle.it-blogs.com.ua/post-72.aspx

Comment: Укажите (добавьте тег), какая именно СУБД используется: oracle, mysql, postgre...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, MS SQL Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использовал SqlServer.

Создадим и заполним тестовую таблицу:

```
create table #t (product char, price int)

insert #t values ('A', 10), ('B', 20), ('C', 45), ('D', 47), ('E', 10), ('F', 60), ('G', 15), ('H', 15), ('I', 90)
```

Запрос:

```
select distinct
    first_value(product) over(partition by num order by num) as [products],
    avg(price) over (partition by num) as [avg]
from
(
    select product, price,
           (row_number() OVER(ORDER BY product) - 1 ) / 3 as [num]
    from #t
) as temp
```

Подозреваю, что запрос сильно неэффективен. На плане выполнения три сортировки. Надеюсь, кто-то приведёт лучший вариант.

---

Вариант, предложенный **i-one** в комментариях:

```
select min(product) as [products],
       avg(price) as [avg]
from
(
    select product, price,
           (row_number() OVER(ORDER BY product) - 1 ) / 3 as [num]
    from #t
) as temp
group by num
```

Судя по плану выполнения, этот запрос эффективнее.

Comment: Возможно как-то избежать вложенного селекта, и все сделать лишь через одну выборку?

Comment: @J.Doe - если бы я знал более простой способ, я бы его написал. Почти уверен, что от вложенного селекта не избавиться. А вот distinct, вероятно, можно убрать. Но что-то никто не предлагает лучшие варианты.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, окно для `first_value` скорее всего имелось ввиду `partition by num order by product`, что касается _"distinct, вероятно, можно убрать"_, то во внешнем запросе можно попробовать обойтись обычной агрегацией, а не по окну: `select min(product), avg(price) from (...) temp group by num`.